# Linux Device Driver - what's wrong with my device_read()?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, device-driver

I've been writing a device **dev/my_inc** that's meant to take a positive integer **N** represented as an ASCII string, and store it internally. Any read from the device should produce the ASCII string representation of the integer **(N+1)**.

However, when I `cat /dev/my_inc`, I only seem to be getting the first half of the `myinc_value` message buffer back in user space.

- If `myinc_value` is 48, `cat /dev/my_inc` yields 4.
- If `myinc_value` is 489324, `cat /dev/my_inc yields` 489.

However, `bytes_read` indicates the entire message was copied into user space. Here is the output from *dmesg*:

```
[54471.381170] my_inc opened with initial value 489324 = 489324.
[54471.381177] my_inc device_read() called with value 489325 and msg 489324.
[54471.381179] my_inc device_read() read 4.
[54471.381182] my_inc device_read() read 8.
[54471.381183] my_inc device_read() read 9.
[54471.381184] my_inc device_read() read 3.
[54471.381185] my_inc device_read() read 2.
[54471.381186] my_inc device_read() read 5. my_inc device_read() returning 7.
[54471.381192] my_inc device_read() called with value 489325 and msg 489325.
```

And when called from the shell:

```
root@rbst:/home/rob/myinc_mod# cat /dev/my_inc
489
```

And the source:

```
// Read from the device
//
static ssize_t device_read(struct file * filp, char * buffer, 
    size_t length, loff_t * offset)
{
    char c;
    int bytes_read = 0;
    int value = myinc_value + 1;

    printk(KERN_INFO "my_inc device_read() called with value %d and msg %s.\n", 
        value, msg);

    // Check for zero pointer
    if (*msg_ptr == 0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    // Put the incremented value in msg 
    snprintf(msg, MAX_LENGTH, "%d", value);

    // Copy msg into user space
    while (length && *msg_ptr) 
    {
        c = *(msg_ptr++);
        printk(KERN_INFO "%s device_read() read %c. ", DEV_NAME, c);
        if(put_user(c, buffer++))
        {
            return -EFAULT;
        }
        length--;
        bytes_read++;
    }

    // Nul-terminate the buffer
    if(put_user('\0', buffer++))
    {
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    bytes_read++;
    printk("my_inc device_read() returning %d.\n", bytes_read);
    return bytes_read;
}
```

Comment: Where are msg and msg_ptr defined/initialised?
Why are you printing out msg before you have even set it?
What is the value of myinc_value?
And what do you mean by "I only get the first byte of myinc_value output to my shell, even though I have bytes_read == 2 at the end of my loop" - two characters is not enough to represent one byte, and - in any case -  you are printing an int in decimal format so the concept of printing just one byte is meaningless.
Also remember that you are not terminating the string returned.

Comment: msg and msg_ptr are defined as type char * in my header file. In the device_open() call myinc_value is initialized to a starting value (defined by a macro) and then the ascii equivalent of myinc_value is copied into msg. 

Ex: myinc_value is initalized to the integer 47. The string "47" is copied into the buffer pointed to by msg. device_read() reads myinc_value into value and increments it, putting the string "48" into msg. When I cat /dev/my_inc, it outputs '4' without a newline (probably because forget to terminate the string), which is the 1st character (byte) of my msg buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that put_user() is defined as a macro so that the post increment operator in

```
if(put_user(c, buffer++))
```

is screwing up - though I don't see how it explains what you are seeing.

Anyway it would be more convenient and more efficient to use copy_to_user() to copy the whole msg.

Comment: Not sure how that explains what I was seeing either, but using copy_to_user() solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it only shows 1 byte is because you are incrementing the msg_ptr before setting it equal to c. It needs to be c = *msg_ptr++; or c = *msg_ptr; msg_ptr++; so that the increment happens after the assignment